# Using LDA for word embedding

Tags: machine-learning, gensim, lda, topic-modeling, word-embedding

I want to do word_embedding using LDA to represent each of documents in my corpus with a vector that each dimension shows one of the detected topics by LDA model, but I don't know how to do it. Any suggestion will be appreciated.
I use python 3.6 and gensim library for LDA.

Comment: This was the most valuable thing I've come across [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zm9NC9uRkk). The LDA part is near the end.

Comment: If you haven't so far, I highly recommend you to work through the gensim tutorials https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html especially the one on the English Wikipedi. That should lead you to what you are looking for!